# Android/PHP RSA encryption/decryption?

Tags: php, android, key, rsa

I would like to encrypt a String on Android and decrypt it with PHP (and vice versa).

The problem is the key generation. What is recommended? Should I create it on Android or with openssl with PHP? I tried the phpseclib.

Creation of the key worked well but when I tried to load the key with BC on Android, it said: InvalidkeyException. It was a PKCS1 key with sha1 in PEM Format. I am talking about the public key.

Can you help me to generate and load a key?

Answer (score 0):

You should always generate the key pair on the device that should store the private key value (in your case, that would be the server containing the PHP code). Otherwise you need to load the key into that device, and to do that securely you may need another key (etc.). You should still make sure that the public key gets distributed to the clients while considering man-in-the-middle attacks (injecting another public key, for instance).

To load the key on Android you need to remove the PEM format/ASCII armor. You can do this by using the Bouncy Castle libraries, or - for Android - [the Spongy Castle libraries](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) which [contain PEM encoding / decoding utilities](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.madgag/scpkix-jdk15on/1.47.0.2/org/spongycastle/openssl/PEMReader.java).

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, JavaForAnroid?